# "Decode error - output not UTF-8" from HTML

Tags: python, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm running BS4 in Python with the code:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit

with requests.Session() as s:
     page = s.get(url)  

doc = page.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

This generates the error: [Decode error - output not utf-8]

Using the following instead yields the same error:

```
doc = UnicodeDammit.detwingle(page.text)
```

And using an ignore:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Gives me the different error:

> AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: What if you would use `page.content` instead of `page.text`?

Comment: @alecxe If I replace the original code with doc = page.content and then pass that doc into beautifulsoup then I get the error: "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'"

Comment: @alecxe  `soup = BeautifulSoup(doc.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'), "html.parser")` throws the same decode error. If I do it like this `soup = BeautifulSoup("html.parser", doc.decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))` then it gives a featurenotfound error, prints the whole html then says "Do you need to install a parser library?"

Comment: Why not just try parse with a different character set than UTF-8? See IANA's [encoding list](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml). Check site's source code for declared encoding.

Comment: Try print soup.get_text().encode('utf-8')

Comment: @Parfait The declared encoding is utf-8 so maybe the issue could be resolved with detwingle but that didn't help either (source: `<!--<meta charset="windows-1252">-->
<meta charset="utf-8">`)

Comment: @SIslam Printing it like that does work and gives me no error however I can't work on it later because of decode error. So I can print where `soup2 = soup.get_text().encode('utf-8')` successfully but if I try to `soup2.findAll('td')` then it fails because "object has no attriubute findall". Any ideas? (Trying to grab a html table)

Comment: Please add some more details of the html and what do you need to extract from.

Comment: @SIslam Here's a snippet of the html: http://pastebin.com/Cjqqs8g7
I'm trying to grab the table that has the class tablehead and all corresponding cells in that table. But even if I ignore the encoding problem, beautifulsoup either says "None" when findAll or gives me a []

Comment: I do not see any unicode char in this snippet!

Comment: @SIslam Wait, did I just goof? Is beautifulsoup looking for a unicode character and not finding it because it's not there? I thought it was naturally in utf-8 and so I could work with it? Arghhh

Comment: Honestly, it is so difficult to answer based on the just the guesses- it would better and cost-effective to get url and what you want! BTW bs4 asks for string or unicode and it will not be able to parse byte streams, hah! Firstly make all response unicode (for ur case- not string) and parse..